# Facebook API: Is it possible to get number of posts in group and group them by members?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook group, and I would like to get the amount of individual posts of each member. Secondly, is it possible to get the amount of posts for a specific time period. Are these even possible? Quite a challenge...

Here's an example:
Firstname Lastname - 10 posts - (August 26, 2013 to September 2, 2013)

How do I do this? By the way, I would prefer to use **PHP** for this project.

Answer (score 0):

All those things are not possible with the Graph API (at least not at the moment), and FQL is deprecated. The only way to do this is to get all entries (with [paging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#paging)) with the /group-id/feed endpoint and do the counting on your own with PHP.